# Фоновый поток с обновлением данных из сервера

Tags: java, android

Что использовать чтобы с `BroadCastReceiver` посылать данные на сервер? И еще хотелось бы узнать как реализовано фоновое обновление данных в приложении "Вконтакте" будь оно закрыто или открыто, т.е как реализованы уведомления о входящем сообщении. Мои предположения что в фоновом потоке запущен `Socket`, но какой фоновый поток для работы с сетью использовать  лучше всего?

Comment: Socket в основном используют для мгновенной передачи информации и когда приложение на переднем плане (чаты например).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вы используете для отправки данных на сервер то и используйте в BroadCastReceiver. Поднимаете новый поток и отправляете. 
Для получения данных в фоне можете использовать [Worker](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html)